How to instrument java code to collect variable allocation data with byte buddy or ASM
how should I instrument my code to get variables allocation data during program execution?
consider this code for example:
public class Test2 {
    public boolean isSerialKeyValid(String serial) {
        if (!serial.toLowerCase().startsWith("@v3")) {
            return isV1V2SerialValid(serial);
        }
        return isV3SerialValid(serial);
    }

    private boolean isV1V2SerialValid(String serial) {
        if (serial.toLowerCase().startsWith("@v1")) {
            String serialValue = serial.split("@v1")[1];
            return isV1ChecksumValid(serialValue);
        }
        String serialValue = serial.split("@v2")[1];
        return isV2ChecksumValid(serialValue);
    }

    private boolean isV1ChecksumValid(String v1Serial) {
        if (!v1Serial.matches("\\d+")) {
            return false;
        }
        String[] items = v1Serial.split("\\d");
        int sum = 0;
        for (String item : items) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(item);
        }
        return sum % 13 == 0;
    }

    private boolean isV2ChecksumValid(String v2Serial) {
        String trimmedSerial = v2Serial.trim();
        if (trimmedSerial.length() != 8) {
            return false;
        }
        return trimmedSerial.matches("[^A-Za-z]+\\w{3}[^A-Za-z]+");
    }

    private boolean isV3SerialValid(String v3Serial) {
        String serialValue = v3Serial.split("@v3")[1];
        return isV3ChecksumValid(serialValue);
    }

    private boolean isV3ChecksumValid(String v3Serial) {
        return v3Serial.length() == 10 && v3Serial.matches(".*@!=.*");
    }
}

public class SampleTestSuit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(validatedSerialKey("@v2123ali34"));
    }

    public static boolean validatedSerialKey (String str) {
        if (str.startsWith("@v1") || str.startsWith("@v2") || str.startsWith("@v1")) {
            Test2 test2 = new Test2();
            return test2.isSerialKeyValid(str);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

When main method runs, I want the record values passed to functions. For the example above here is some sample output that I like to get:
{
              methodName: TestSuit2.Test2#isSerialKeyValid,
              parametersValue:[
                  {
                      paramName: serial,
                      paramValue: "@v2123ali34"
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              methodName: TestSuit2.Test2#isV1V2SerialValid,
              parametersValue:[
                  {
                      paramName: serial,
                      paramValue: "@v2123ali34"
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              methodName: Java.Lang.String#toLowerCase,
              parametersValue:[
                  {
                      paramName: ?,
                      paramValue: "@v2123ali34"
                  }
              ],
          },

I also used google allocation-instrumenter.  But that library can not get me variables names and their runtime value(or I didn't find any resource for that purpose)
Should i use a library like byte buddy or ASM? My target JDK is 8 FYI.
Thanks

Your sample output looks like a log of method invocations. Of course, tools to monitor allocations won’t provide that, as method invocations and (object) allocations are entirely different things. As often, the problem start with defining the goal.

My ultimate goal is to capture program variables values during a test execution. I will use that data to understand why a test case fails or passes. The question mentioned above is a major step for my ultimate goal @Holger

Am I taking correct approach?

Which approach are you taking?

I am trying to use ASM to instrument the code and get required data. But I am not sure if I am taking correct decision.

Sounds like a viable approach. There might be existing tools for that task which do similar things under the hood.
